# What make and model wireless USB dongle works with no issues?

Tags: hardware, wireless

I have Ubuntu Desktop Edition 10.10 installed on my laptop, and Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10 on my partners netbook and I would like to install Ubuntu on my dads old and failing desktop but the only thing that is stopping me is the fact that his current USB Wireless Dongle doesn't work with Ubuntu (It's a Belkin Wireless G (Model No. F5D7051)).

I just need to find a cheap USB wireless dongle that works out of the box for my dads computer that is compatible with Ubuntu, can anyone recommend any?

Comment: The belkin F5D7051 is known to have a few different chipsets, do you know which yours has?

Comment: On the front it says 802.11g 125 HSM, I have another wireless USB dongle which doesn't work, it is a D-Link DWA-111 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few Edimax EW-7711UAN dongles in use. N(150) speeds for £9.99 a go. Uses the Ralink RT2870 chipset.

http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=NW-078-EX

Its built-in aerial does help with signal. I've found the some of the smaller, hidden-aerial dongles can have signal issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked it on the link on the other answer and apparently it doesn't work out-of-the-box. Did you have to do anything to make it work? If so, please could you provide a step-by-step guide?

Comment: It does. Might just be something with newer kernels but mine have worked fine for well over a year. Edit: come to think of it, I did used to have to blacklist rt2800usb... but that was a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this list: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported